# Adding an acetal to basic water

Tags: organic-chemistry

If you add an acetal to a solution containing water with a little bit of NaOH, will no reaction occur due to the stability of an acetal in the presence of a base?

Comment: Pretty much. A key step of acetal hydrolysis is protonation of one of the oxygens.

Comment: Acetals are liable in acidic conditions; they are stable in basic conditions.